# CSS: Align Text To top with no spacing between text lines

Tags: php, css

I am working with a php document that has tables as well as an image, the way its set up is I have a table with 3 columns, two with text and one with a picture. The problem that I am running into is that the images are all different sizes which cause my text lines to cause spacing in between them, is there a way to format the text to retain its original formatting? Here is an example of what I am talking about  http://www.cnghl.biz/cnghldb/test.php?PlayerID=2818

Here is the CSS

```
  <style>
 a {text-decoration:none;}
  }
  td {
  vertical-align: top;
   }
 td img {
vertical-align: top;
 }
 .space { 
 line-height: .3 em; 
 }
 .wrap {
float:right;
}
</style>
```

And here is the PHP

```
  Echo      "<td width='659'><div align='center'>";
  Echo        "<table width='602' border='0'>";
  Echo          "<tr>";
  Echo            "<td colspan='3'><h1>".$row['FirstName']." ".$row['LastName']."</h1>  </td>";
  Echo            "</tr>";
  Echo          "<tr>";
  Echo            "<td width='164'><strong>Birthdate:</strong>".$row['DOB']."</td>";
            $DOB = $row[DOB]; //dd.mm.yyyy
            $user_date = new DateTime($DOB);
            $curr_date = new DateTime();
            $age_cal = $curr_date->diff($user_date);
 Echo            "<td width='219'><strong>Age:</strong>".$age_cal->y;"</td>";
 Echo            "<td width='205' rowspan='6'><div align='center'><img  src=\"http://www.cnghl.biz/cnghldb/images/".$iPlayerID.".jpg\">";
 Echo          "</tr>";
 Echo          "<tr>";
 Echo            "<td><strong>Nation:</strong>".$row['Nation']."</td>";
 Echo            "<td><strong>CNGHL Team:</strong>".$row['CNGHLRights']. "</td>";
 Echo            "</tr>";
 Echo          "<tr>";
 Echo            "<td><strong>Position:</strong>".$row['Position']. "</td>";
 Echo            "<td><strong>Weight:</strong>".$row['Weight']. "</td>";
 Echo            "</tr>";
 Echo          "<tr>";
 Echo            "<td><strong>Height:</strong>".$row['Height']. "</td>";
 Echo            "<td><strong>NHL Team:</strong>".$row['Team']. "</td>";
 Echo            "</tr>";
 Echo          "<tr>";
 Echo            "<td><strong>Draft Year:</strong>".$row['CNDraftYR']."</td>";
 Echo            "<td><strong>Draft Position:</strong>".$row['CNDraftPOS']."</td>";
 Echo            "</tr>";
 Echo          "<tr>";
 Echo            "<td height='25'><strong>Drafted By:</strong>".$row['DrTeam']."</td>";
 Echo            "<td><strong>Current Salary:</strong></td>";
 Echo            "</tr>";
 Echo        "</table>";
 Echo      "</div></td>";
 Echo      "<td width='141'>&nbsp;</td>";
 Echo    "</tr>";
 Echo  "</table>";
 Echo "</div>";
```

I have tried to adjust the size of the image but that does not solve the problem, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why was the OP downvoted? Not a particular interesting question, but I'm upvoting to remove the downvote. It's a well-posed question.

Comment: It's like standing on the top of a majestic valley… :)

Comment: The code posted does not reproduce the problem (essential parts of the actual code are missing), it is PHP and not HTML, and an answer that does not address the question has been accepted. So it is really unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely do not use tables for layout purposes. By the way, this is the expected behavior of HTML tables, stretching their size to the content.

You can achieve this using `div`s, both **solving your problem** and having a **more semantic markup**, and having a **cleaner markup**.

I would also suggest you wrap your player's data into a *Definition list* (`dl` element) for a more semantic approach.

<kbd>[Example implementation](http://jsbin.com/tiveh/1/)</kbd>

Comment: Advising to simply replace tables by divs and then on top calling _that_ “more semantic markup” can only get you a downvote …

Comment: Thanks for the comment, however `div`s are definitely a more semantic way to approach the issue; they have their place and their meaning. Even if they don't say much about the content, by the mere fact of substituting a misleading markup (tables for non-tabular data), they are making the markup more semantic (and cleaner, and simpler). Furthermore, my example shows how to use **Definition lists** to markup the data inside instead of tables. I would appreciate if you'd remove the downvote if my edit clarifies my intentions.

Comment: That example you added only afterwards; and I still consider calling divs “_more_ semantic” a _misleading_ answer.

Comment: Yes, I added it as a clarification. As I said, by the virtue of removing misleading markup, it automatically makes the markup more semantic. Using `div`s to wrap the content sections and using a definition list to wrap the data is the most semantic way to solve this problem. If you don't believe so, please propose a more semantic alternative. Also, please specify how does this answer not solve the OP problem, which is the point of posting an answer.

Comment: _“and using a definition list to wrap the data”_ – well put that _into_ your answer than (and not just uncommented into an example).

Comment: I added that to my answer. I didn't because it is not strictly necessary to solve the OP problem, but more of a suggestion unrelated to his problem. Is it enough for you to take your downvote back now?

Comment: Does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is the images being different sizes, you could give each image a specific width. Or if you don't want to adjust the images themselves, give the div/td that the image is in a specific width and height that is equal to the largest image and doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

Your `rowspan` is set to 6 but you have 7 `<tr>` in your table. The `td { vertical-align: top; }` is what you need for your CSS.